# How can I print date in dd-mmm-yyyy format in java ?

Tags: java

I'm able to calculate future date using

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); // +days      
    return cal.getTime();
```

but the returned date format is : Fri Nov 23 12:09:46 PST 2018

how to override it with  dd-mmm-yyyy format ??

Comment: Check out the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class

Comment: Which calendar uses more than 100 months?

Comment: There's no way this isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); // +days      
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
return formatter.format(cal.getTime());
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toFormattedString(10, "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        System.out.println(toFormattedString(10, "dd-MM-yyyy"));
    }

    static String toFormattedString(int days, String pattern) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); // +days
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        return formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18-Feb-2021
18-02-2021
```

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the modern date-time API.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(toFormattedString(10, "dd-MMM-uuuu"));
        System.out.println(toFormattedString(10, "dd-MM-uuuu"));
    }

    static String toFormattedString(int days, String pattern) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate afterTenDays = today.plusDays(days); // +days
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.getDefault());
        return formatter.format(afterTenDays);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18-Feb-2021
18-02-2021
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Please stop teaching use the old time objects in `java.text`, let go throught `java.time`. Also there is a well explained duplicate

Comment: it worked , perfect Thanks

Comment: @rev No problem.

Comment: @rev Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.